# How to break out of a loop if there is an indexOutOfBoundException?

Tags: java, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

Is it possible to break out of a loop if there is an `indexOutOfBoundException`? For example:

```
int v = 987;  
int c = 783;  
int[] someArray = new int[23];       
   do{  
     //do stuff  
     if(someArray[68] == indexOutOfBoundException){ // How can this be done? 
       break;  
     }  
   }while(v > c);
```

I know that this `someArray[68]` itself would throw an error, but can you prevent that from being an error and simply break out of a given loop?

Comment: What is an `Exception`? What can you do with them?

Comment: legend has it that if wasnt caught it would break out for you

Comment: You can catch it, but it's a lot easier to just check it beforehand `if(someValue < someArray.length){ // do shizzle }`.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis if there is an exception do not keep going with the loop

Comment: These exception is the result of bad programming and should be fixed during development. The regular way to deal with exceptions in general in Java is to wrap exception-throwing code into `try-catch` blocks.

Comment: (When replying to someone, don't leave a space between the `@` and their name.) That doesn't answer my question, if you take a second to really answer it, you will get your answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry for my mistake. How does the space affect it though? I am new to this site.

Comment: @SimionMita [Space doesn't belong in the reply syntax.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking is whether there's a way to break out of the loop BEFORE an exception is raised.  To do that you can simply test the array index against the array size:

```
int v = 987;  
int c = 783;  
int[] someArray = new int[23];       
do{  
    // do stuff  
    int arrayIndex = (some expression);
    if (arrayIndex >= someArray.length) break;
    int anotherValue = someArray[arrayIndex];
    // do something else
}while(v > c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why this shouldn't be hard. Just add try catch.

```
int v = 987;  
int c = 783;  
int[] someArray = new int[23];       
   do{  
     //do stuff  
     int val;
     try{
         val = someArray[68];
     }catch(Exception e) {
         break;
     }
     // do some other operation with the val 
   }while(v > c);
```

And BTW, this is just an abuse of try catch, even if this is a solution you shouldn't use it any way.

Comment: At the very least the `catch` should catch ONLY `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @HotLicks you're right, but any Exception that can happen here (NullPointer or ArrayIndexOutOfBounds) seems ridiculous to me.